# What's wrong with select2 4.x optgroup?

Tags: jquery-select2

"optgroup" works well in 3.x versions, but in versions starts all of 4.x I have only "No results found" in dropdown. What's wrong? Official haven't issue about this bug.

My jade:

```
select.select-js(style="width: 100%")
        option
        optgroup(label="lbl1")
          option(value='0') Opt Text
          option(value='1') Opt Text
          option(value='2') Opt Text
          option(value='3') Opt Text
        optgroup(label="lbl2")
          option(value='4') Opt Text
          option(value='5') Opt Text
          option(value='6') Opt Text
          option(value='7') Opt Text
        option 123
```

And JS:

```
function LoadSelect2 () {
  $('.select-js').select2({
    minimumResultsForSearch: Infinity,
    maximumInputLength: 0,
    theme: "vesta",
    templateResult: formatRes,
    width: 'resolve',
    placeholder: function () {
      $(this).data('placeholder');
    }
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
placeholder: function () {
  $(this).data('placeholder');
}
```

Must to delete this